# C# WindowsForms - Draw a line and get the closest integer numbers

Tags: c#, charts, line, draw

I have a Windows Forms application where 2 drones will appear on a chart telling it's x,y position. That's already done.

But now, I want to be able to draw a path (for example: red for drone1 and blue for drone2) in the chart and get a list of values (x,y) where the drone should move to.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJrCv.png)

**So my questions are:**

How can i draw a line in the chart? Maybe it can be a used a picturebox on top of it?

How can I retrive a list of the points (x,y) in the chart where the line was drawn?

Thank you.

Comment: Download Microsoft Samples " https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61

Comment: Why do I need this?

Comment: The samples have a wide variety of different options which will give your answer.

Comment: I can't say that those examples are actually very good. Drawing a Line chart is as simple as adding datapoints with the x- and y-values. Lines do not 'consist' of points, they connect points! If you want to calculate points on a line all you need is a little bit of trivial math. In addition to the lines connecting the DataPoints of a LineChart you could also draw onto the Chart in its prePaint event. Probably not necessary.